# It does not work select2 ruby on rails 5

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap-3

[image]

> It does not work select2 does not bring me any value, like bring value, I'm new to programming and I want to learn a lot, thanks for the help

**application.css.scss**

```
    *= require toastr
    *= require jquery-ui
    *= require select2
    *= require select2-bootstrap
    *= require_tree .
    *= require_self
    */



    @import 'bootstrap-sprockets';
    @import 'bootstrap';
    @import 'bootstrap-datetimepicker';
    @import "select2";
    @import "select2-bootstrap";
    @import "font-awesome-sprockets";
    @import "font-awesome";
```

**application.js**

```
    //= require jquery
    //= require turbolinks
    //= require jquery_ujs
    //= require jquery-ui/widgets/autocomplete
    //= require autocomplete-rails
    //= require select2-full
    //= require bootstrap-sprockets
    //= require moment
    //= require moment/es
    //= require bootstrap-datetimepicker
    //= require toastr
    //= require pickers
    //= require_tree .




    $( "#dropdown" ).select2({
        theme: "bootstrap"
     });
```

**meetings.js**

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#ajax-example').select2({
      ajax: {
        url: "/meetings.json",
        dataType: "json",
        results: function(data, page) {
          return { 
            results: $.map( data, function(meeting, i) { 
              return { id: meeting.id, text: meeting.name } 
            } )
          }
        }
      }
    });
  });
```

**index.html.erb**

** (index current)**

```
   <input type="text"  id="ajax-example" />
```

**meetings_controller.rb**

```
 def index
   @meetings  = Meeting.order('name').all  
 end
```

**Gemfile**

```
 gem 'bootswatch-rails'
 gem 'simple_form'
 gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3', '>= 3.3.7'
 gem 'jquery-rails'
 gem 'will_paginate', github: 'jonatack/will_paginate'
 gem 'ransack'
 gem 'will_paginate-bootstrap'
 gem "select2-rails"
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your meetings controller to this:

```
respond_to :html, :json

def index
  @meetings = Meeting.order('name').all
  respond_with @meetings
end
```

What that does is allow the controller to respond with a JSON array of you meetings models. The `select2` plugin needs this to be able to fetch the data it will display in the select menu.

Here is a tutorial on this topic: http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/using-select2-with-ruby-on-rails-treehouse-quick-tip